# Returning head and tail means from list of vectors

Tags: r

I need to calculate the mean (or other summary functions) on the top x and bottom x portions on list of vectors of varying lengths.

Here is a list of 3 vectors of different lengths similar in format with what I am working with:

```
t <- list(a = exp(-4:3), b = exp(-2:12), c = exp(-5:3))
```

Ideally, I would like a single vector of numbers for each type of means (I manually ran mean(head(t$a),2)) and mean(tail(t$a),2)) for each vectors):

Ideal output yielding a nameless vector of means of the first two elements from each vector:

```
[1] 0.2516074   1.859141    0.09256118
```

Second vector of means for last two entries in each vector:

```
[1] 1.859141    15064.77    1.859141
```

Looking for a clever lapply-type construct to get a vector of numbers for each means without the attached names (in this case a,b,c). Thanks!

Comment: `unname(lapply(t, function(x) c(mean(head(x, 2)), mean(tail(x, 2)))))`.  Btw, might not want to use `t` as a variable name, as it's a base R function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
n = 2
v = lapply(t, function(i) mean(head(i, n)))
```

The variable `v` is list. So to get a vector, just use `unlist`

```
v = unlist(v)
```

To extract the numbers use `as.vector`

```
as.vector(v)
```

For the tail, just use

```
lapply(t, function(i) mean(tail(i, n)))
```

Comment: I'm guessing you meant for one of those to say `tail`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` you can wrap this in a function:

```
sapply(dat,function(x,length=2)
  c(mean(head(x,length)),mean(head(x,length))))
# a         b          c
# [1,] 0.03405135 0.2516074 0.01252679
# [2,] 0.03405135 0.2516074 0.01252679
```